# Trying to enable P2P on T-Mobile Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, wireless-bridge, p2p

I have T-Mobile Home Internet, which runs directly of their 5G network. T-Mobile, like a lot of carriers, ban P2P connections on their network. I was able to get around this on my PC (to torrent a file) by using Google One's VPN, which was great.

The issue is on my Nintendo Switch, which has no support for VPN that I have found. I can't set up the VPN on my router because T-Mobile's router configuration is through an app that has no advanced settings. I have even tried turning the VPN on for my phone and then hotspot that connection, which has not worked to allow the switch to use P2P.

My only option seems to have something to use with LAN/WLAN bridging by creating a bridge adapter. I haven't gotten this to work, however. When I try to create my network bridge on Windows 10, the Google One VPN immediately turns off.

There is a game on my Switch that uses P2P connections for its online gaming (Super Smash Bros Ultimate). I am hoping someone has some insight or ideas that may help me figure this out.